# Data Preparation for Metaanalysis - using Metafor

Tags: r

In order to calculate the effect sizes and run the meta-analysis for a dichotomous predictor of a continuous outcome (*d* or *g*), a dataframe consisting of the mean's, sd's, and sample size for each study is required.

I was trying to write some code that will create the required dataframe from the raw data. This will mean that this process will not have to be completed manually for each study.

*Example Raw Dataset*

```
Study <- c("andrew", "andrew", "andrew", "andrew", "peters", "peters", "peters", "jess", "jess", "jess")
Score = c(100, 308, 584, 241, 241, 111, 431, 123, 321, 411)
Sex = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1)
data = cbind(Score, Sex, Study)
data

 >     Score Sex Study   
 > [1,] "100" "1" "andrew"
 > [2,] "308" "1" "andrew"
 > [3,] "584" "1" "andrew"
 > [4,] "241" "2" "andrew"
 > [5,] "241" "2" "peters"
 > [6,] "111" "1" "peters"
 > [7,] "431" "2" "peters"
 > [8,] "123" "2" "jess"  
 > [9,] "321" "1" "jess"  
> [10,] "411" "1" "jess"
```

How can I turn it into the following file for *metafor* dividing the data by sex and by study?

```
Study       MeanMale   MeanFemale   SDMale    SDfemale    NrowsMale    NrowsFemale
andrew         X           X          X          X            X             X
peters         X           X          X          X            X             X
jess           X           X          X          X            X             X
```

I would imagine using describeBy, statsBy, or Splitdata with sapply would work but getting it into the required format is messy. The next aim would be to introduce a year column as well E.g.,

```
Study <- c("andrew", "andrew", "andrew", "andrew", "peters", "peters", "peters", "jess", "jess", "jess") 
Score = c(100, 308, 584, 241, 241, 111, 431, 123, 321, 411)
Sex = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1) 
Year = (1992, 1992, 1992, 1992, 1988, 1988, 1988, 1977, 1977, 1977) 
data = cbind(Study, Year, Score, Sex)
```

To produce the following data.frame

```
Study      Year  MeanMale   MeanFemale   SDMale    SDfemale    NrowsMale    NrowsFemale
andrew     1992    X           X          X          X            X             X
peters     1988    X           X          X          X            X             X
jess       1977    X           X          X          X            X             X
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use the devel version of `data.table` i.e. v1.9.5.  Instructions to install the devel version are [`here`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation).

We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by 'Sex' and 'Study', get the `mean`, `sd` and `.N` (nrows), and use `dcast` (from `data.table` which can take multiple `value.var` columns) to reshape from 'long' to 'wide' format.

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
dcast(setDT(data)[, list(Mean= mean(Score), SD= sd(Score), Nrows=.N), 
.(Sex, Study)], Study~ c('Male', 'Female')[Sex], 
          value.var=c('Mean', 'SD', 'Nrows'))
#     Study Female_Mean Male_Mean Female_SD   Male_SD Female_Nrows Male_Nrows
#1: andrew         241  330.6667        NA 242.79484            1          3
#2:   jess         123  366.0000        NA  63.63961            1          2
#3: peters         336  111.0000  134.3503        NA            2          1
```

#### EDIT

From @Arun's comments, the `dcast` from `data.table` accepts multiple functions as well.

```
dcast(setDT(data), Study ~ c('Male', 'Female')[Sex],
        fun.agg=list(mean, sd, length), value.var="Score")
#    Study Female_mean_Score Male_mean_Score Female_sd_Score Male_sd_Score
#1: andrew               241        330.6667              NA     242.79484
#2:   jess               123        366.0000              NA      63.63961
#3: peters               336        111.0000        134.3503            NA
#   Female_length_Score Male_length_Score
#1:                   1                 3
#2:                   1                 2
#3:                   2                 1
```

Or we can use `reshape` from `base R` after getting the `mean`, `sd`, `nrow`  using `aggregate`.

```
d1 <- do.call(data.frame,aggregate(Score~., transform(data, Sex=c('Male',
 'Female')[Sex]), FUN=function(x) c(Mean=mean(x), SD=sd(x), Nrows=length(x))))

reshape(d1, idvar='Study', timevar='Sex', direction='wide')
#  Study Score.Mean.Female Score.SD.Female Score.Nrows.Female Score.Mean.Male
#1 andrew               241              NA                  1        330.6667
#3   jess               123              NA                  1        366.0000
#5 peters               336        134.3503                  2        111.0000
#  Score.SD.Male Score.Nrows.Male
#1     242.79484                3
#3      63.63961                2
#5            NA                1
```

#### data

```
data <- data.frame(Score, Sex, Study)
```

Comment: @Arun Thanks, didn't know about that.  It is much better

Comment: The code works well to change the numerical coding of Sex into named (male, female) headings. Thanks for your help, for anyone else trying to run this remember that you cannot have .NA's or just run this beforehand:                                              `Data <- Data[complete.cases(Sex),]`

Comment: Would there be some way @Arun or @Aakrun to alter this code to insert a year column. i.e. the raw dataset has a "Year" column which indicates the year each study was run and we want the final data.frame to have the "Study" and respective "Year" Columns.  This would make the headings:   `Study, year, Score.Mean.Female, Score.SD.Female, Score.Nrows.Female, Score.Mean.Male,  Score.SD.Male, Score.Nrows.Male`

Comment: @ConalMonaghan I am guessing that you can modify the `dcast` formula to include `year` i.e. `dcast(setDT(data), Study + year ~ ....`  (not tested) an example would have been better.

Comment: @ConalMonaghan  Please post as a separate post

Comment: No problems, I modified the initial question to have a second section with the year included for an example, Thanks for all your help! @akrun

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty straight forward to do with dplyr and reshape2. We convert Sex to a named factor, use mutate to get SD and sample size by group, then melt and cast the data to get the means by group with nice variable names:

```
require(reshape2); require(dplyr)

data$Sex <- factor(data$Sex, levels = c(1, 2), labels = c('Male', 'Female'))
data <- mutate(group_by(data, Study), SD = sd(Score), Nrow = length(Score))
data <- melt(data, id.vars = c('Study', 'Sex'))
data$value <- as.numeric(data$value)
dcast(data, Study ~ variable + Sex, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: I think it should be `group_by(data, Sex, Study)`. And I'd argue that having to melt to only cast back makes this anything but straightforward.